# Send billing info from woocommerce checkout page to paypal checkout form

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, forms, paypal

I have a theme using Woocommerce and PayPal Checkout. The checkout page in my theme has a form to input Billing Address info. My only method of payment is via PayPal Checkout. If a user starts the payment process and selects to enter their card info without logging into PayPal, they are presented with another form to input their billing info, within the PayPal window.

This means a lot of users are filling out the billing info in the checkout page and then having to fill out the same info for PayPal. Is there any way to provide the billing info from the form on my site to the PayPal Checkout service so that the information gets auto-populated? I'm not able to find anything related to this in the documentation of the [PayPal Checkout](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/) service.

Comment: This is all the info you need: https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-pre-populate-my-customer's-paypal-sign-up-form-ts1372